# Combine two tables into one entity framework? (SQLite)

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp-xaml

I am using the EntityFramework.SQLite library and for the life of me can not figure out how to combine two tables together into a temporary table for display purposes in xaml code.

Here's the code for my two tables I want to combine which is about all I am using right now besides a class for my temp table called CategoryList (this is part of the business/data logic dll library):

```
Partial Public Class CategoryList
        Public Sub New()
            Me.CategoryInfo = New CategoryReference
            'Me.CategoryCode = New HashSet(Of CategoryCodes)
            Me.CategoryCodes = New CategoryCodes

        End Sub


        Public Property MyId As Integer

        <Key, ForeignKey("CodeID")>
        <Required>
        Public Property CodeID As Integer

        <Key, ForeignKey("CategoryID")>
        Public CategoryID As Integer

        'Public Property CategoryCode As ICollection(Of CategoryCodes)
        Public Property CategoryInfo As CategoryReference
        ' Public Property CategoryInfo As ICollection(Of CategoryReference)
        Public Property CategoryCodes As CategoryCodes
    End Class

    <Table("CategoryCodes")>
    Public Class CategoryCodes 'category shortnames/codes 
        <MaxLength(100)>
        <Required>
        Public Property CategoryCode As String
            Get
                Return _CategoryCode
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _CategoryCode = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _CategoryCode As String

        '<NotNull>
        ' <PrimaryKey>
        '<Unique(Name:="UQ__CategoryCodes__0000000000000081_CategoryCodes", Order:=0)>

        <Key>
        <Required>
        Public Property CodeID As Integer
            Get
                Return CategoryCode
            End Get
            Set(value As Integer)
                _CodeID = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _CodeID As Integer
    End Class
    <Table("CategoryReference")>
    Partial Public Class CategoryReference 'table design for category data

        <MaxLength(100)>
        Public Property CategoryName As String
            Get
                Return _CategoryName
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _CategoryName = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _CategoryName As String
        <MaxLength(100)>
        Public Property CategoryDescription As String
            Get
                Return _CategoryDescription
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _CategoryDescription = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _CategoryDescription As String

        '<Unique(Name:="UQ__CatagoryReference__000000000000005F_CatagoryReference", Order:=0)>
        <ForeignKey("CodeID")>
        <Required>
        Public Property CodeID As Integer
            Get
                Return _CodeID
            End Get
            Set(value As Integer)
                _CodeID = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _CodeID As Integer

        '<Unique(Name:="UQ__CatagoryReference__000000000000005A_CatagoryReference", Order:=0)>
        <Key>
        <Required>
        Public Property CategoryID As Integer
            Get
                Return _CategoryID
            End Get
            Set(value As Integer)
                _CategoryID = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _CategoryID As Integer

    End Class
```

It may seem long but the tables are very simple and the get/set blocks make it look long (A vb.net editor can turn them into simple property's if she/he wishes). I may be using the CategoryList class wrong but here's where I use it in my xaml datasource in my main application code (I have business logic/data processing in a dll library):

```
  Private Property ViewModel As List(Of UIELLUWP.DataAccess.CategoryList)
    Dim categories As New UIELLUWP.DataAccess.SQLiteDb

        ViewModel = categories.Categories.ToList
```

Errors received with current code:
I receive an error that Table "CategoryList" does not exist when I run the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution I found out to this question was to add asnotracking because tracking was taking place.